# Firebase: How to authenticate using emp_id

Tags: android, firebase

I want to use employee_id for the authentication using firebase because I see only emailid, phn_no or google/facebook.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Firebase Authantication you can get all user informations easily. As I understand from your question, you can get user informations like this ;

```
 FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```

You can get now user ID by using this  `user.getUid()`